# AlarmReceiver in Android never receiving an alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

My AlarmManager class extends BroadcastReceiver and Ive tried everything but it never seems to receive my alarm.

here is my method in the main class

```
public void setApp(int startHour, int startMin, int endHour, int endMin) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmManager.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PhoneManagerActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Toast.makeText(PhoneManagerActivity.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar startCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCalendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

    if (startCalendar.getTimeInMillis() <= calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
        startCalendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);
    }
    Am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);         
}
```

Here is my receiver class

```
public class AlarmManager extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("beast", "alarm");

        try {
            Log.i("beast", "alarm recieved");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone set",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // AdamApp3Activity adam = new AdamApp3Activity();
            ((PhoneManagerActivity)context).setRinger();
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, PhoneManagerActivity.class);
            newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have defined it as a receiver in my xml but it never receives my alarm